# How to convert mp4 file to wav with the same duration?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to convert an long Mp4 file to WAV with the same duration.
I tried to use ffmpeg with the args "aresample=async=1000" but there is still a difference:

- the duration of the origin long MP4 is 03:28:05.936
- the duration of the converted WAV is 03:28:05.35

Is there any way can convert the MP4 file to WAV with the complete same duration?

Thanks!

Comment: The audio stream may be slightly shorter. The duration ffmpeg shows for a file is based upon the longest stream.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for your comment. Is there any pattern about the shorter audio steam? Is the missing part must happen at the beginning of the video steam?